# Getting JavaScript variable in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm rendering a dynamic calendar's values using JavaScript. I'm displaying the selected date in an  element. How can I get the date (value of  element generated by JavaScript) in Django?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200">

    <title>Booking</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper2">
            <div class="price">
                <p>Best price of 60,00 €</p>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="display-date">
                    <p>Start date</p>
                    <a id="start-date" name="start"></a> <!-- I need the value of this element in Django -->
                </div>
                <div class="display-date">
                    <p>End date</p>
                    <a id="end-date" name="end"></a>
                </div>
                <h4>Enter your full name</h4>
                <input type="text" name="fullname">
                <h4>Enter your e-mail</h4>
                <input type="text" name="email">
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Request appointment">
            </form>
        </div>


        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="outline"></div>
            <header>
                <div class="icons">
                    <span id="prev" class="material-symbols-rounded">chevron_left</span>
                    <p class="current-date"></p>
                    <span id="next" class="material-symbols-rounded">chevron_right</span>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="calendar">
                <ul class="weeks">
                    <li>Sun</li>
                    <li>Mon</li>
                    <li>Tue</li>
                    <li>Wed</li>
                    <li>Thu</li>
                    <li>Fri</li>
                    <li>Sat</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="days"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
const CURRENT_DATE = document.querySelector(".current-date");
days_tag = document.querySelector(".days");
previous_next_icon = document.querySelectorAll(".icons span");

// Getting new date, current year and motnh
let date = new Date(),
current_year = date.getFullYear()
current_month = date.getMonth();

const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

const render_calendar = () => {
    let first_days_of_month = new Date(current_year, current_month, 1).getDay(); // Getting first day of month
    last_date_of_month = new Date(current_year, current_month + 1, 0).getDate(); // Getting last date of month
    last_day_of_month = new Date(current_year, current_month, last_date_of_month).getDay(); // Getting last day of month
    last_date_of_last_month = new Date(current_year, current_month, 0).getDate(); // Getting last day of previous month
    let li_tag = "";

    for (let i = first_days_of_month; i > 0; i--) { // Creating li of previous month days
        li_tag += `<li class="inactive">${last_date_of_last_month - i + 1}</li>`;
    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= last_date_of_month; i++) { // Creating li of all days of current month
        // Adding active class to li if the current day, month, and year matched
        let is_today = i === date.getDate() && current_month === new Date().getMonth() 
                        && current_year === new Date().getFullYear() ? "active" : "";
        li_tag += `<li class="${is_today}">${i}</li>`;
    }

    for (let i = last_day_of_month; i < 6; i++) { // Creating li of next month first days
        li_tag += `<li class="inactive">${i - last_day_of_month + 1}</li>`;
    }

    CURRENT_DATE.innerText = `${months[current_month]} ${current_year}`;
    days_tag.innerHTML = li_tag
}

render_calendar()

previous_next_icon.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // If clicked icon is previous icon then decrement current month by 1 else increment it by 1
        current_month = icon.id === "prev" ? current_month - 1 : current_month + 1;

        if(current_month < 0 || current_month > 11) { // If the current month is less than 0 or greater than 11
            // Creating a new date of current year & month and pass it as date value
            date = new Date(current_year, current_month);
            current_year = date.getFullYear(); // Updating current year with new date year
            current_month = date.getMonth(); // Updating current month with new date month
        } else { // Else pass new Date as date value
            date = new Date();
        }
        render_calendar();
    })
})

const START_DATE = document.getElementById("start-date");
const END_DATE = document.getElementById("end-date");

current_date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-UK")
current = new Date();
next_day = new Date(current.getTime() + 86400000).toLocaleDateString("en-UK");

START_DATE.innerHTML = current_date;
END_DATE.innerHTML = next_day;
```

I tried using

```
request.POST.get("start", False)
```

and

```
request.POST["start"]
```

but it always returns False or None, as if there's nothing in the  element.

I know that there are many similar questions, but I'm wondering if there's anything I can do in this case. Do I have to switch to Node.js as a backend to achieve this?

Comment: It doesn't show up in the form because it's not a form input element.  It's not `<input>`, or `<textarea>`, or a checkbox, or a radio button, or any other kind of input element.  It's an `<a>` element, and those are not submitted as form data.  (Yes they are are inside a `<form>` tag, but that doesn't matter.)  I don't understand how this form is useful, since the start and end dates aren't actually input elements.

Comment: @JohnGordon The form is useful for submitting e-mail and full name (they're used for another function out of this question's scope). This part isn't fully functional yet, but when the user clicks on a date in the calendar, the ```<a>``` element's value will become that date. The ```<a>``` element is used only for displaying the selected date.

Comment: If you want to submit something as form input ... then it has to be some kind of form input element.  Not sure how else I can say it.

Comment: @JohnGordon I made the ```<a>``` element an input with minor code adjustments and everything works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: HTML elements shouldn't be used at random https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics